# Problem with running flask on Python locally

Tags: python-3.x, flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

when trying to run Flask in any way I have found on the internet I still get an Error

```
  File "c:\python36\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 5: invalid
start byte
```

I guess it's because there is non ascii character in my name. I tried on my other account with only ascii characters and the problem still occurs. Result is the same with with DEBUG mode. Can anyone give me some tips on this, please? The code is th official basic example from Flask's website.

```
    D:\kiwiAdmission\flask>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "kiwi_flask.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 894, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 557, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func

    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 771, in run_command
    threaded=with_threads, ssl_context=cert)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 814, in run_sim
ple
    inner()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 774, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 660, in make_se
rver
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 577, in __init_
_
    self.address_family), handler)
  File "c:\python36\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "c:\python36\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "c:\python36\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 5: invalid
start byte
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc Did, it's edited. sorry

Comment: This might be related, https://bugs.python.org/issue26227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, just renamed my host name! to only ascii name